# My regular expression does not check the names correctly

Tags: php, regex

I created this function to check Spanish names and it is not working.

This is the string that I am passing to the function:

```
"Ángel Manuel"
```

Here you have the function:

```php
/**
* checks First Name or Last Name
*
* @access public
* @param bool $valid
* @param string $name
* @return bool
*/
    
public static function checkName($valid, $name) {
    if(!preg_match('/^(?=.{3,18})[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóú]+(?:\s[A-ZÁÉÍÓÚ][a-zñáéíóú]+)?/', $name)) {
        $valid=false;
    }
    return $valid;
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What concrete issue are you facing? According to this https://regex101.com/r/swPdWn/1 it's fully matching your input string.

Comment: How are you using the code? Why do you pass `$valid` as an argument?

Comment: What about poor `José Gómez-Iglesias`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to

- add `$` at the end of the lookahead to actually restrict max length of the matched string, `(?=.{3,18}$)` and at the end of the regex pattern (or `(?=\X{3,18}$)` to allow 3 to 18 any graphemes)
- add `u` flag since your input is a Unicode string
- use `\p{Lu}` to match any Unicode uppercase letters, and `\p{Ll}` to match any Unicode lowercase letters
- and just return `true` or `false` depending on the result of `preg_match`, no need to pass `$valid` as function argument.

You can use

```php
public static function checkName($name) {
    if(!preg_match('/^(?=.{3,18}$)\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)?$/u', $name)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=.{3,18}$)` - string must have 3 to 18 chars (`(?=\X{3,18}$)` to allow 3 to 18 any graphemes)
- `\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+` - one Unicode uppercase letter followed with one or more lowercase letters
- `(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)?` - an optional sequence of a whitespace and then one Unicode uppercase letter followed with one or more lowercase letters
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: `return (bool)preg_match('/^(?=.{3,18}$)\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+(?:\s\p{Lu}\p{Ll}+)?$/u', $name);`